# Comparing bits efficiently ( overlap set of x )

Tags: c#

I want to compare a stream of bits of arbitrary length to a mask in c# and return a ratio of how many bits were the same. 
The mask to check against is anywhere between 2 bits long to 8k (with 90% of the masks being 5 bits long), the input can be anywhere between 2 bits up to ~ 500k, with an average input string of 12k (but yeah, most of the time it will be comparing 5 bits with the first 5 bits of that 12k)

Now my naive implementation would be something like this:

```
bool[] mask = new[] { true, true, false, true };
float dendrite(bool[] input) { 
    int correct = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i<mask.length; i++ ) { 
        if ( input[i] == mask[i] ) 
            correct++;
    }
    return (float)correct/(float)mask.length;
}
```

but I expect this is better handled (more efficient) with some kind of binary operator magic?

Anyone got any pointers?

EDIT: the datatype is not fixed at this point in my design, so if ints or bytearrays work better, I'd also be a happy camper, trying to optimize for efficiency here, the faster the computation, the better.

eg if you can make it work like this:

```
int[] mask = new[] { 1, 1, 0, 1 };
float dendrite(int[] input) { 
    int correct = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i<mask.length; i++ ) { 
        if ( input[i] == mask[i] ) 
            correct++;
    }
    return (float)correct/(float)mask.length;
}
```

or this:

```
int mask = 13; //1101
float dendrite(int input) { 

    return // your magic here;
} // would return 0.75 for an input 
  // of 101 given ( 1100101 in binary, 
  // matches 3 bits of the 4 bit mask == .75
```

ANSWER:
I ran each proposed answer against each other and Fredou's and Marten's solution ran neck to neck but Fredou submitted the fastest leanest implementation in the end.  Of course since the average result varies quite wildly between implementations I might have to revisit this post later on. :) but that's probably just me messing up in my test script. ( i hope, too late now, going to bed =)

```
sparse1.Cyclone
1317ms   3467107ticks 10000iterations
result:    0,7851563

sparse1.Marten
288ms   759362ticks 10000iterations
result:    0,05066964

sparse1.Fredou
216ms   568747ticks 10000iterations
result:    0,8925781

sparse1.Marten
296ms   778862ticks 10000iterations
result:    0,05066964

sparse1.Fredou
216ms   568601ticks 10000iterations
result:    0,8925781

sparse1.Marten
300ms   789901ticks 10000iterations
result:    0,05066964

sparse1.Cyclone
1314ms   3457988ticks 10000iterations
result:    0,7851563

sparse1.Fredou
207ms   546606ticks 10000iterations
result:    0,8925781

sparse1.Marten
298ms   786352ticks 10000iterations
result:    0,05066964

sparse1.Cyclone
1301ms   3422611ticks 10000iterations
result:    0,7851563

sparse1.Marten
292ms   769850ticks 10000iterations
result:    0,05066964

sparse1.Cyclone
1305ms   3433320ticks 10000iterations
result:    0,7851563

sparse1.Fredou
209ms   551178ticks 10000iterations
result:    0,8925781
```

( testscript copied here, if i destroyed yours modifying it lemme know. https://dotnetfiddle.net/h9nFSa )

Comment: Is your mask of arbitrary length as well? If you were dealing with integer types, you could use xor to get the difference, then count the remaining bits.

Comment: If you can xor your number with the mask, the bits can then be counted using the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/109023/622391).

Comment: @cubrr The mask doesn't change after object initialization but is of variable length. editing my question so that it is declared outside of the function now. 
I'll go look at the linked question SimonMᶜKenzie gave and see if I can manage to xor the correct bits myself. 
Thanks guys!

Comment: argh, @SimonMᶜKenzie any chance you could spoonfeed me the answer based on my example code? I tried to grok your link but I fear it (still) is a bit beyond my skill level.

Comment: is the input always an array of bool?

Comment: @Fredou it doesn't have to be, i thought it would be the most memory efficient way to store variable length binary sequences

Comment: what is the maximum number of bit that you would be comparing? more than 64? (ulong)

Comment: So what's the maximum length of the input? Will it fit into a 64-bit `long`? My suggestion is really only feasible if your values are stored as numbers, because then you can xor easily, using the [^ operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkacc7k1.aspx), plus the bits can be counted using bitwise operations as per the answer I linked earlier.

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie, i think we can assume that it would not work as number, his logic check for identical 1 and 0, in  a int, it would be checking 32 bits and not only let say 4 like in his example

Comment: I modified my answer so that a few more examples are given; the mask is a known array of bits. the input is an arbitrary length bits, but the masklength is the only part i care about

Comment: Thanks Simon, my mask length can be constricted, so i can discard the parts of the input i don't care about and then represent them as numbers and do your xor compare... should work indeed, wonder how fast it'll be, cheers

Comment: what is the source of the array? manipulating it into a different format could make it slower, better to keep it in the original format to do the processing, is it a stream of bytes? string? or ... ?

Comment: it comes in from various sensor inputs over a serial bus, but i only process when the entire set of linked sensors is read. they're boolean toggles mostly, hence the bool[] array, but that's just by choice, there's 1 sensor in there (crude image sensor) that generates occasional burst of larger data. the dream is to have the same processing routine running on all inputs, hence the weird variable size model instead of the classic distributed one you see in, for instance, sparse coding. 
if that makes sense ; ) @Fredou

Comment: ideally, in the end, we put this dendrite function right after input so we cut of input after max(mask.length) is reached and wait for reset (hardware interrupt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about [this one - dotnetfiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LprOL2)

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int a = Convert.ToInt32("0001101", 2);
            int b = Convert.ToInt32("1100101", 2);

            Console.WriteLine(dendrite(a, 4, b));

        }

        private static float dendrite(int mask, int len, int input)
        {
            return  1 - getBitCount(mask ^ (input & (int.MaxValue >> 32 - len))) / (float)len;            
        }

        private static int getBitCount(int bits)
        {
            bits = bits - ((bits >> 1) & 0x55555555);
            bits = (bits & 0x33333333) + ((bits >> 2) & 0x33333333);
            return ((bits + (bits >> 4) & 0xf0f0f0f) * 0x1010101) >> 24;
        }
    }
}
```

64 bits one [here - dotnetfiddler](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tso6dW)

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //                                                                                      1
            ulong a = Convert.ToUInt64("0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001101", 2);
            ulong b = Convert.ToUInt64("1110010101100101011001010110110101100101011001010110010101100101", 2);

            Console.WriteLine(dendrite(a, 4, b));

        }

        private static float dendrite(ulong mask, int len, ulong input)
        {
            return 1 - getBitCount(mask ^ (input & (ulong.MaxValue >> (64 - len)))) / (float)len;            
        }

        private static ulong getBitCount(ulong bits)
        {
            bits = bits - ((bits >> 1) & 0x5555555555555555UL);
            bits = (bits & 0x3333333333333333UL) + ((bits >> 2) & 0x3333333333333333UL);
            return unchecked(((bits + (bits >> 4)) & 0xF0F0F0F0F0F0F0FUL) * 0x101010101010101UL) >> 56;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: adding this one to test set! =) looks very elegant, y'all have very cool ways to count bits =) also, major props for the fiddle link, didn't know it existed!
will mark as answer if fastest

Comment: modifying it for larger masks would be to change 32 in this line?  (int.MaxValue >> 32 - len)))  ? i'm still trying to grok what's going on =)

Comment: you need to also change the getbitcount function and play with the value, i will try to check if i can quickly do it

Comment: @BobVerkouteren 64 bits version  available

Comment: getBitCount is so leet i have tears in my eyes =) i'm studying it and also the cardinality by @Mårten Wikström below but I fear I'll need to sleep on it and re-fiddle with them in the morning (with my binary logic cheatsheet next to my coffee) to truly get them. Thanks!

Comment: @BobVerkouteren have fun reading this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight

Comment: Thanks @Fredou yours won the race (results in answer) 
Cool! Hamming Weight seems exactly the stuff I was looking for!!!

Answer (score 1):

I would change the code to something along these lines:

```
// hardcoded bitmask
byte mask = 255; 
float dendrite(byte input) { 
  int correct = 0;

  // store the xor:ed result
  byte xored = input ^ mask;

  // loop through each bit 
  for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    // if the bit is 0 then it was correct
    if(!(xored & (1 << i)))
      correct++;
   }
   return (float)correct/(float)mask.length;
}
```

The above uses a mask and input of 8 bits, but of course you could modify this to use a 4 byte integer and so on.

Not sure if this will work as expected, but it might give you some clues on how to proceed.

For example if you only would like to check the first 4 bits you could change the code to something like:

```
float dendrite(byte input) { 
  // hardcoded bitmask i.e 1101
  byte mask = 13;  
  // number of bits to check
  byte bits = 4;

  int correct = 0;

  // store the xor:ed result
  byte xored = input ^ mask;

  // loop through each bit, notice that we only checking the first 4 bits
  for(int i = 0; i < bits; i++) {
    // if the bit is 0 then it was correct
    if(!(xored & (1 << i)))
      correct++;
   }
   return (float)correct/(float)bits;
}
```

Of course it might be faster to actually use a `int` instead of a `byte`.

Comment: if we follow his example, checking a byte would be looking at  8 bits, not 4, depend what is the input

Comment: Thanks for  if(!(xored & (1 << i)))  maybe you already gave me the answer here. If you did, and I understand it correctly, shifting my input to the right size to then xor compare... um, will test until i actually understand your answer, and if faster will comment and check as answer. Lol, may the fastest algorithm win.  (optimizing for speed, not mem atm)

Comment: @BobVerkouteren, you should update your question mentioning this 2bit to 300k bits

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this code:

```
static float dendrite(ulong input, ulong mask)
{
    // get bits that are same (0 or 1) in input and mask
    ulong samebits = mask & ~(input ^ mask);

    // count number of same bits
    int correct = cardinality(samebits);

    // count number of bits in mask
    int inmask = cardinality(mask);

    // compute fraction (0.0 to 1.0)
    return inmask == 0 ? 0f : correct / (float)inmask;
}

// this is a little hack to count the number of bits set to one in a 64-bit word
static int cardinality(ulong word)
{
    const ulong mult = 0x0101010101010101;
    const ulong mask1h = (~0UL) / 3 << 1;
    const ulong mask2l = (~0UL) / 5;
    const ulong mask4l = (~0UL) / 17;

    word -= (mask1h & word) >> 1;
    word = (word & mask2l) + ((word >> 2) & mask2l);
    word += word >> 4;
    word &= mask4l;

    return (int)((word * mult) >> 56);
}
```

This will check 64-bits at a time. If you need more than that you can just split the input data into 64-bit words and compare them one by one and compute the average result.

Here's a .NET fiddle with the code and a working test case:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/5hYFtE

Comment: ooh, thanks, will adapt and run this one against input as well and compare runtimes! mask won't be longer than 64 in my first tests anyway. will mark as answer if fastest

Comment: This should be pretty fast.

Comment: thanks for the fiddle, was already testing it out there, as with some other answers it'll take me a while to understand everthing that's going on here, thanks a bunch educational.